# How can I attach plain jQuery when displayed on the desktop and attach jQuery Mobile when displayed on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, desktop

I am building a website that I want to use jQuery Mobile to do the javascript when on mobile devices, but since jQuery Mobile is not supported by all desktop browsers yet I want normal jQuery to be attached. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it on the client:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              function isMobileDevice() {
                var index = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile");
  return (index > -1);
              }
              function loadJQuery() {
                if(isMobileDevice())
                     document.write("<script type='text/javacript src='"+path_to_mobile_jquery+"'></script>");
                else
document.write("<script type='text/javacript src='"+path_to_normal_jquery+"'></script>");
              }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadJQuery();">
      <!-- Content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps build up an enum of probable browser types and then test against `window.navigator.userAgent`? You can use a library like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) to test for features, but this won't get you the actual browser type. There is no (yet) userAgent prop to identify browser class (desktop, tablet, mobile, etc.), so you're stuck doing a dumb UA comparison.

Projects like [51 Degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) aim to simplify this evaluation, but they incur hidden costs--namely, 51 Degrees takes upwards of 10 seconds to evaluate the client browser and redirect accordingly. Of course, in your case, you want conditional styling--not redirect. This suggests that a `window.navigator.userAgent` check might lend itself to an `if(true) document.write('<javascript resource />')` type approach.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to test the browser request header (User-Agent) on the server and then bind the framework accordingly:

e.g. see
http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php
User-Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18